# Rails: Selecting a record in an object, given the object's ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given:

```
@products = Products.all

# Do some code to choose a specific id of a record from @products
chosen_product_id = 1
```

Current code makes a second call:

```
Product.find(chosen_product_id)
```

... which is inefficient. How do I select the correct record from the existing object without making another database call?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do that when you can give conditions at SQL level through `:conditions` or `where`

Comment: I agree with @Chirantan. What do you mean by inefficient? Making two calls may not be inefficient. In Object Relational Mapping frameworks you do queries all the time.

Comment: @Chirantan - I'm grabbing a large set of records, then using BOTH the large set and my chosen single record for two different purposes.

Comment: @hade Even with query caching, I'd like to not have to make a repeat trip to the database if I already have the data I need in the larger set.

Comment: @jmccartie, for a large database, I would definately make two trips to db, rather than looping through all the values locally. How long can it really take to make one-id call against indexed table?

Comment: Your inability to imagine why someone needs to do something is not a reason not to do it. It's just a demonstration or your failure at being creative. I'm so sick of drones with an utter lack of imagination telling people with the spark of creativity they should stop being creative because the ill informed and unimaginative can't squeeze forth even an ounce of creative juice. If you don't have an answer and your only arguments are arguments from ignorance (argumentum ad ignorantiam) or arguments from personal incredulity then that is your failing. Not the asker of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@products.detect {|p| p.id == chosen_product_id }
```

Comment: Q: where is the documentation for `detect` ?